# Uncaught ReferenceError for filter group items

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter

This is all my code.
This is all my code. I want to know. Why do I want to run all the filters together? I'm having trouble.

```
function customFilter(list, field, value){

    return list.filter(item=> {
            if(typeof(filter) === 'Object'){
                value.foreach(val => {
                    if (item[field] === value){
                        return item[field] === value

                    }
                });
            }
            return item[field] === value
        });
}
function checkedInputs() {
    return [...querySelector('.filter_type .customCheck')].map((c) => c.checked);
}


let filterCheckboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.customCheck');

filterCheckboxes.forEach(checkbox =>checkbox.addEventListener('change' , (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    var checkboxes = checkedInputs();
    var filteredList = FlyList;
    checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
       let filterTypeElement = findFilterTypeElement(checkbox);
       if (filterTypeElement) {
         let field = filterTypeElement.getAttribute('data-field');
         let val = e.target.value;
         console.log(field,val);
         filteredList = customFilter(filteredList, field , val);
       }
    });
}));

function getParents(el, parentSelector /* optional */) {

    // If no parentSelector defined will bubble up all the way to *document*
    if (parentSelector === undefined) {
        parentSelector = document;
    }

    var parents = [];
    var p = el.parentNode;

    while (p && (p !== parentSelector || p.parentNode)) {
        var o = p;
        parents.push(o);
        p = o.parentNode;
    }
    parents.push(parentSelector); // Push that parentSelector you wanted to stop at

    return parents;
}

function findFilterTypeElement(el)
{
    var result = null;
    var parents = getParents(el);

    parents.forEach((item) => {
        if(hasClass(item,'filter_type') && result == null)
        {
            result = item;
        }   
    });
    return result;
}

function hasClass(element, className) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + className + ' ') > -1;
}
```

To make you understand. I got a picture of my code error.

[image]

Uncaught ReferenceError: querySelector is not defined at checkedInputs (functions.js:1013) at HTMLLabelElement.checkbox.addEventListener (functions.js:1022)

You will see the code and image code error. Please help. Where is the code problem?

Comment: What exactly is the error? Also, `querySelector` is not a standalone function, it's on `document`

Comment: and I think you want to use `document.querySelectorAll` to get the collection

Comment: I've raised the text of the error. Under the photo

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I modified the code.

Answer (score 0):

> The Document method [querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first Element within
>   the document that matches the specified selector, or group of
>   selectors. If no matches are found, null is returned.

the return value of `.querySelector()` an element and not a collection of elements and therefor it is not iterable, that's why you're getting the error, use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead .

replace

```
function checkedInputs() {
    return [...querySelector('.filter_type .customCheck')].map((c) => c.checked);
}
```

with

```
function checkedInputs() {
    return [...querySelectorAll('.filter_type .customCheck')].map((c) => c.checked);
}
```